# How to Validate an ID (Primary Key) in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a field in a php page to enter the register number and check the Details.
[Here is the ScreenShot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etfmG.jpg)
Register Number is the ID in the table.
So how can i validate the register number entered in the page with the register number in the Database.

Here is the Code:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
include 'connect1.php';
if (isset($_POST['login']))
{
    $_SESSION['regno']= $_POST['regno'];
    $regid = $_SESSION['regno'];
    if  (empty($regid)){
        echo "<p class='echo'> *The Field Should not be empty </P>";
    }
    else if ($regid = )//WHAT SHOULD BE CHECKED HERE   ?????? 
    {
        header('location: details.php');// If not empty, Details page is loaded.
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Login
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="reg">
   <h1 class="h1">Registered User?</h1>
    <form action="" method="POST" >
   <input type="number" class="textbox" name="regno" placeholder="Registration Number"/><br/>
   <input type="submit" class="login" name="login" value="Check">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to check if the number entered in the field is in the Database??

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Yes you should check it in database. Use mysqli to connect to your db and select product where id = registration_number.

Comment: Run select query using where clause and check num rows. If num rows ==0 then invalid entry.Else valid .

Comment: "SELECT id FROM table_name where id = '$regid'"

Comment: This is way to broad a question. You are basically asking someone to code it for you, **thats not the way SO works**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is in your pattern use the logic and implement it.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
 // escape variables for security
 $_SESSION['regno'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['regno']);
 $regid =$_SESSION['regno'];
if  (empty($regid)){
    echo "<p class='echo'> *The Field Should not be empty </P>";
}
else
{
  $sql="select regno from your_table where regno='".$regid."'";
  $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
  $number=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if($number > 0 ){
   header('location: details.php');// If not empty, Details page is loaded.
  }else{
     echo "<p class='echo'> *Not Found </P>";
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a request like this :

```
Select * From table_name Where ID = the_checked_ID
```

If it returns nothing, the ID is not in your database

Comment: No security checks! Also need to implement in **PHP**..

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<?php
$current_path = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; 
//include database connection code here :)
if(isset($_POST['regno']))
{ 
    $regnumber = $_POST['regno'];
    $query = "Select * From your_table_name Where ID = '$regnumber'";
    if($query_run = mysql_query($query))
    {
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query_run);
        if($num_rows == 1)
        {
            echo "This is registered User";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Please Register";
        }
    }
} 
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Login
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="reg">
   <h1 class="h1">Registered User?</h1>
    <form action="<?php  echo $current_path ?>" method="POST" >
   <input type="number" class="textbox" name="regno" id="regno" placeholder="Registration Number"/><br/>
   <input type="submit" class="login" name="login" value="Check">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```